# How to calculate the distance of a point to a symmetric vector equation?

Tags: vectors

New here, sorry for asking a textbook question but I'm trying to make this more general.

What's the distance from A(2,1,3) to the line x=3, y=-1? The answer is $\sqrt{5}$

So it seems like in this question there isn't a directional vector, which is required in calculating the distance.

Comment: Can we use calculus?

Comment: the line is given by $x=3,y=-1$ and $z=?$

Comment: Calculus is not required. z is not given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B(3,-1,t)$ is a point on our line such that $AB$ is perpendicular to our line.

Thus, $\vec{AB}(1,-2,t-3)$ and $\vec{AB}\cdot\vec{(0,0,1)}=0$.

Thus, $t=3$ and $\vec{AB}(1,-2,0),$ which gives $AB=\sqrt{1^2+(-2)^2+0^2}=\sqrt5$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If you want the directional vector write the equation of the line in the form:

$$
(x,y,z)^T=t(0,0,1)^T+(3,-1,0)^T
$$

anyway you can use two points on the line as you can see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance3-Dimensional.html).

Comment: So when z is not given, it is 1 by "default"?

Comment: No, $z$ can assume any value! it is $z=t\cdot 1\qquad  \forall t \in \mathbb{R}$.